# CDN redirect for the API's JavaScript SDK is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, documentation, authentication

The API's JavaScript SDK is [listed](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib) as https://api.stackexchange.com/js/2.0/all.js.

However, `GET` request produces the following response:

```
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently  
Location:    https://api-v2cdn.sstatic.netjs/all.js
```

This `Location` is incorrect.
It should be https://api-v2cdn.sstatic.net/js/all.js instead.

Comment: [Near duplicate bug](http://stackapps.com/q/3116/7653).

Comment: @BrockAdams What you call "botched" I call "disagreement". Sorry about the unhelpful, I may have a misunderstanding of what that actually means — but I did disagree with most of it. I only used parts of it (including tags). As for the stole — it did that automatically when I chose "improve". Do you want me to link to you from the comment field if anything like that arises again? I'll update my understanding of helpfulness flag.

Comment: I guess the only thing to do is to check "helpful", in the future, when you use 90+ percent of the suggested edit, as you did in this case.  You probably should check helpful if you use ***any*** part of a suggested edit -- unless the rest is majorly bad.

Comment: Yes, I thought on it a bit and I agree with you on using any part. I'll follow that approach in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally my first vacation in two years, and I break something right before going offline.  Sorry about that.

This was fixed in the latest deploy.